# Jenkins Pipelining using Containers

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to setup Pipelining using Jenkins.  However, my Jenkins instance itself is a container. My goal is to run each layer of my application (frontend, backend, database) using docker, but I don't want to run docker within docker.

Does it make sense to convert Jenkins from a container to a VM? Or is there a way to overcome the docker within docker inception problem?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just trying to understand what you meant by running docker within docker? Each container will be running on host machine itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use docker out of docker rather than docker in docker, there's a great article about that by one of docker's creator here: https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/.

This is what I am using and it works pretty well.

There is a gotcha with this: Your bind mount would be relative to host filesystem not the jenkins containers filesystem, thus I recommend having `jenkins_home` a bind mount rather than a named volume, and having the bind mount in the same path on the host and in the container, as jenkins will generate path to files relative to workspace (which is within jenkins_home usually).

Comment: This looks promising and I will try this out! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Or is there a way to overcome the docker within docker inception problem?

You can use container orchestration tool Kubernetes or Mesos.

Comment: Ultimately, Kubernetes is the long term solution, but we don't have the resources yet.

Comment: Look at Mesos/Marathon solution. In dev environment you can use just one dedicated server.

Comment: I'm looking into this now.  Thank you sir!